# Convert stream of hex values to 16-bit ints

Tags: python, casting

I get packages of binary strings of size 61440 in hex values, somehting like:

```
b'004702AF42324fe380ac...'
```

I need to split those into batches of 4 and convert them to integers. 16 bit would be preferred but casting this later is not a problem. The way i did it looks like this and it works.

```
out = [int(img[i][j:j+4],16) for j in range(0,len(img[i]), 4)]
```

The issue im having is performance. Thing is i get a minimum of 200 of those a second possibly more and without multithreading i can only pass through 100-150 a second.

Can i improve the speed of this in some way?

Comment: `numpy` would likely help.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you saying that the incoming string of data is 61,440 characters - i.e. 15,360 hex values? Are you splitting this b-string into four parts - i.e. does the img list have 4 elements? I have some ideas but need clarification before I can [try to] develop a solution

Comment: @DarkKnight its 61440 characters each representing 1 hex value. I split them in groups of 4 so the img list has 15360 values in the end. Basically each package is a part of an image and every 4 characters is 1 pixel.

Comment: maybe first assing `img[i]` to local variable and it will need less time to search this element.

Comment: Do you control the receiving of that stream? If yes, then you can make  a buffer of 4 and convert it into int as soon as you receive the full 4 bytes

Comment: @furas good point, that speeds it up some 5%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and found that not multi-threading but multi-processes are what I need. That gave me a speedup from 220 batches per second to ~370 batches per second. This probably bottnecks somewhere else now since i only got 15% load on all cores but puts me comfortably above spec and thats good enough.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def combine(img):
    return np.array([int(img[j:j+4],16) for j in range(0,len(img), 4)]).reshape((24,640))

p = Pool(20)
img = p.map(combine, tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a rewrite of my earlier offering showing how multithreading does, in fact, make a very significant difference - possibly depending on the system architecture.

The following code executes in ~0.05s on my machine:-

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
import concurrent.futures

N = 10
R = 61440
IMG = []
for _ in range(N):
    IMG.append(''.join(random.choice('0123456789abcdef')
                       for _ in range(R)))
"""
now IMG has N elements each containg R pseudo randomly generated hexadecimal values
"""

def tfunc(img, k):
    return k, [int(img[j:j + 4], 16) for j in range(0, len(img), 4)]

R = [0] * N

start = datetime.now()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    """
    note that we pass the relevant index to the worker function
    because we can't be sure of the order of completion
    """
    for i in range(N):
        futures.append(executor.submit(tfunc, IMG[i], i))
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        k, r = future.result()
        R[k] = r

"""
list R now contains the converted values from the same relative indexes in IMG
"""

print(f'Duration={datetime.now()-start}')
```

Comment: this looks nice ill give this a try. Is this a speedup though? The baseline is 0.8s for 200 runs, this is 0.05s for 10 runs (1s for 200 if it scales linear)?

Comment: The performance is likely to depend on your system's architecture. Typically, multi-threading is not well suited to purely CPU-intensive work (which this is). I published this "solution" really just to show how it could be done and not necessarily how it should be done

Comment: thats quite allright, can you still set `N=200` and tell me how long it takes?

Comment: With N=200 I see:- Duration=0:00:00.992748

Answer (score 0):

I don't think multi-threading will help in this case as it's purely CPU intensive. The overheads of breaking it down over, say, 4 threads would outweigh any theoretical advantages. Your list comprehension appears to be as efficient as it can be although I'm unclear as to why img seems to have multiple dimensions. I've written the following simulation and on my machine this consistently executes in ~0.8 seconds. I think the performance you'll get from your code is going to be highly dependent on your CPU's capabilities. Here's the code:-

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
hv = '0123456789abcdef'
img = ''.join(random.choice(hv) for _ in range(61440))
start = datetime.now()
for _ in range(200):
    out = [int(img[j:j + 4], 16) for j in range(0, len(img), 4)]
print(f'Duration={datetime.now()-start}')
```

Comment: i wouldnt break it down for each package but since an image consists of 20 packages (hence the second dimension of img) i could have each thread do 5 list comprehensions